# Postgresql in PHP SELECT COLUMN result is null

Tags: php, postgresql

I have:

```
 <?php

     .........
       $query="select osm_id, name, official_name, official_status, phone,'healthcare:speciality', way, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(way,4326)) as way2 from opengeo.test_point";
  $result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Проблема с запросом " . $query . "<br/>";
        echo pg_last_error();
        exit();
    }

    $geojson = array(
                     'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
                     'features'  => array(),
                     'crs' => array(
                                    'type' => 'EPSG',
                                    'properties' => array('code' => '4326')
                     )
    );
    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {

          $feature = array(
                           'type' => 'Feature',
                           'id' => $myrow["osm_id"],
                           'geometry' => json_decode($myrow["way2"], true),
                           'geometry_name' => 'way',
                           'properties' => array(
                                                 'name' => $myrow["name"],
                                                 'official_name' => $myrow["official_name"],
                                                 'addr:housenumber' => $myrow["addr:housenumber"],
                                                 'phone' => $myrow["phone"],
                                                 'healthcare:speciality' => $myrow["healthcare:speciality"],
                                                 'addr:street' => $myrow["addr:street"],
                                                 'opening_hours' => $myrow["opening_hours"]
                           )
          );
          // Add feature array to feature collection array
          array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);

    }

    // Close database connection
    pg_close($db);

    header('Content-type: application/json',true);
    echo json_encode($geojson);

?>
```

and $myrow["healthcare:speciality"] return null always, i tried with other columns and all columns with ":" returned null?

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working:

```
   $query="select osm_id, name, official_name, official_status, phone,\"healthcare:speciality\", way, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(way,4326)) as way2 from opengeo.test_point";
```

change ' for columns(with colon) on \"